# create bootable disk of os x mavericks with ubuntu

Tags: live-usb, gui, macosx

Is there a graphical method to create a bootable disk of mac os x 10.9 from ubuntu.
I found one method : "http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/293168-guide-how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-109-mavericks-usb-install-drive-on-linux/" (but it is with command line). Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not terribly easy, and the folk at Apple seem to make it this way on purpose.  I suppose you know that running OSX on anything other than Apple hardware is not supposed to be done?

A good link for alternate boot options and tools for OSX can be found at http://www.tonymacx86.com/home.php